# OrientDB: Filter select on super class

Tags: orientdb

Using the OrientDB console there is a command to show all records with a class that extends a base class.

```
browse class Asset
```

This returns all records that have a class (Object1, Object2) that extends Asset.

I'm looking for a SQL command that can do the same.

Currently this query does not return the same set of records.

```
SELECT * V where @class = 'Asset'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To retrieve all the records from Object1 and Object2, a simple select query from the superclass name should work :

```
select from Asset
```

Answer (score 5):

you can also use  `instanceof`  operator,

eg.

```
 select from V where @this instanceof 'Asset'
```

This makes sense especially in v. 2.1 where you have multiple inheritance, in cases when you want to retrieve documents that are subclasses of two different parent classes

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for all superclasses of a given class, this worked for me:

```
select superClasses from (select expand(classes) from metadata:schema) where name = "myClassName"
```